# Rails 3 ActiveRecord#includes bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email
  has_many :accounts
end
```

As far as i know, in order to select all accounts that for all users with email match a pattern, we must do a join

```
Account.joins(:user).where("users.email ILIKE ?", '%pattern%') -> work
```

And here comes the magic, replacing includes with joins, still work like a charm

```
Account.includes(:user).where("users.email ILIKE ?", '%pattern%') -> work
```

But

```
Account.includes(:user).where("users.email ILIKE ?", '%pattern%').count -> error
```

Any explanation ? isn't includes just for Eager Loading only ?

Comment: can you post the error you are getting ?

Comment: try,. `Account.includes(:user).where("users.email ILIKE ?", '%pattern%').length`

Comment: Includes actually does a left outer join if you are using the table in where condition that's why you are getting result

Comment: it this command working for you? `Account.includes(:user).where("users.email ILIKE ?", '%pattern%')`

Answer (score 1):

Because without explicit reference `includes` loads relation in a separate query. Take a look at rails console:

```
[11] pry(main)> Account.includes(:user)
  AccountsUser Load (4.6ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts"
  User Load (11.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (...

[11] pry(main)> Account.includes(:user).where("users.email ILIKE ?", '%pattern%').to_sql
  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE (users.email ILIKE '%admin%')
```

That is why you are getting an error - `users` table is not referenced in a query. To reference users table use either `references` or `eager_load`:

```
Account.includes(:user).references(:users).where("users.email ILIKE ?", '%pattern%').count
```

or

```
Account.eager_load(:user).where("users.email ILIKE ?", '%pattern%').count
```

Note that `includes` works with association names while `references` needs the actual table name

Comment: But the problem is `Account.includes(:user).where("users.email ILIKE ?", '%pattern%')` still working fine, it only breaks when call a count on it `Account.includes(:user).where("users.email ILIKE ?", '%pattern%').count`